# How do you make Bootstrap responsive on a phone but not a narrow desktop browser

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've found this page for turning off responsiveness in Bootstrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/

What I'd like is to have one page that is responsive on the phone, but is not responsive when viewed on a desktop browser that has been resized to be narrow.

It looks like I could do most of what is on that page by detecting the device and then using JavaScript.  Is there a simpler way that I'm missing or some other idea?

Comment: No real answer, sorry. What do want to achieve with that? Doing something like this destroys many advantages of the idea of responsive design and adds the complexity of traditional seperate views for desktop and mobile.

Comment: Nope. Only feature detection can help you. Modernizr comes to mind. Only other way is reading the user-agent header but I would stay miles away from that.

Comment: I'm going to agree with @ThisWillDolt and venture that you may not be doing responsive design the right way if you're trying to do this. Are you dropping features for phone? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's an external requirement. I don't disagree that it's not preferred, but many sites behave this way -- for example, StackOverflow.  The issue is that when the site is extremely complex (like SO) and the phone version hides a lot of things, the transition is jarring if you are just narrowing the window.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to force the mobile menu to toggle on a phone but you might have to worry about disabling other breakpoints. 480 represents the width of the smartphone, you can edit this as needed.

```
     $(window).resize(function() {
     if ($(window).width() <=480 ) {
      $('.navbar-collapse a').click(function(e) {

      $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
     });
     }
     });
```